# Explicit model binding using route segment names

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two models, `Thread` and `Post`, and the relationship (one `Thread` has many `Post`s) is defined in the `posts()` methods in `Thread` model. `Thread`s are resolved through the slug field:

```php
// in Thread.php...
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Now, each `Post` has an `index` field starting from `1` -- it identifies the position of this `Post` in the sequence. For example, in

```php
/threads/some_thread_slug/posts/4
```

with the route definition being

```php
Route::get('threads/{thread}/posts/{post}, '.....');
```

`4` is NOT the id of the `Post`, it's the index of the `Post` in relation to other `Post`s with the same `thread_id`. In other words, if the `Thread` with the slug of `some_thread_slug` has 10 `Post`s, then the route above should resolve to the `Post` with `index` (again, not `id`) of 4:

```php
// Thread $thread is automatically resolved through the 'slug' field...
$post = $thread->posts()->where('index', $index)->first() // $post->index == 4
```

The goal is to now resolve `Post`s through the `index`. I can certainly tweak it through the `RouteSerivceProvider`, but the problem is that I don't have access to the parent `Thread` slug:

```php
Route::bind('post', function (int $index) {
    // Hmmm.. How do I know which Thread this $index relates to?
    // By no means are these indices unique!
});
```

My solution so far is to find the parent `Thread` by directly accessing the URL component (e.g. `some_thread_slug`) and fetching the corresponding model. BUT this is dangerous because the index in `Request::segment()` is not always the same. Does Laravel offer any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `callable` parameter of the `Route::bind()` method can accept a 2nd parameter which is an instance of the `Illuminate\Routing\Route` class. You can use that instance to get the `Thread` from the route `parameters`.

Example:

```
Route::bind('post', function (int $index, Route $route) {
    $thread = $route->parameter('thread');

    return $thread->posts()->where('index', $index)->first();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to do prefix `Route` like so: `\Illuminate\Routing\Route`, with the leading backslash. Works well! The only thing is `$route->parameter('thread')` returns a `string`. There is no way to automatically resolve `Thread` here, right?

Comment: There is. If you bind `{thread}` to be an instance `Thread` using route-model binding, it should resolve properly.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!